# Show categories in the sidebar of Outlook?

Tags: ms-office

Is it possible to show Categories in the Navigation Pane (left sidebar) of Outlook 2011? If so, how?

Comment: No, it's not possible.  s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a Smart Folder for each of your categories to accomplish this.  In the search bar, search for "category:yourcategoryname" and hit enter.  The Search tab in the Ribbon will appear.  There, you can select "Save", which will save your search as a Smart Folder.

Comment: Ugh. Bummer. That's gonna be a pain as I have A LOT of categories. Thanks!